# cppcheck thinks there is a mismatch in alloc and dealloc

Tags: c++, cppcheck

The cpp-check error is: `error   mismatchAllocDealloc    false   Mismatching allocation and deallocation: val2`

What should I do to fix this error?

```
void MainWindow::ParseDemo(char *pBuf)
{
  char* val2 = new char[256];
  for (int i = 0; i < 254; i++)
  {
     val2[i] = pBuf[i+305];
  }
  val2[254] = 0; // 0-Termination
  QString sunit(val2);
  DoStuff(sunit);
  delete val2;
  // ... 
}
```

Comment: It does not say that there's a leak, it says that there's a *mismatch*. It would probably also say that if you wrote `free(val2);`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> ```
> error mismatchAllocDealloc false Mismatching allocation and deallocation: val2
> ```

`new` and `new []` need to be used in a consistent manner with `delete` and `delete []`, that's why cppcheck complains.

> What should I do to fix this error?

Write `delete [] val2;`, that should fix it.

BTW, that's not indicating a memory leak directly, but it could become one easily, because it's basically undefined behavior.